# Send file from one endpoint to another in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to send a file that I receive in 'testFile1' to 'testFile2'. I don't know if the stream I am creating is the right way to do it or if I have to retrieve the file on 'testFile2' in another way. Any help?

```vb
    <HttpPost>
    <Route("testFile1")>
    Function postTestFile1() As IHttpActionResult
      Try
        Dim files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files
        If files.Count = 0 Then Throw New Exception("No file")
        Dim file = files(0)
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9000/api/test/testFile2")
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"
        req.ContentLength = file.ContentLength
        Dim stream = req.GetRequestStream
        Dim fileData As Byte()
        Using BinaryReader As New BinaryReader(file.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8)
          fileData = BinaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength)
        End Using
        stream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length)
        Dim response As WebResponse = req.GetResponse
      Catch ex As Exception
        Return InternalServerError()
      End Try
    End Function

    <HttpPost>
    <Route("testFile2")>
    Function postTestFile2() As IHttpActionResult
      Try
        Dim files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files
        Dim requestStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream
        If files.Count = 0 Then Throw New Exception("No file")
        Dim file = files(0)
        'Do the necessary with the file
        Return Ok()
      Catch ex As Exception
        Return InternalServerError()
      End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Is this failing in some way?  More importantly, if these operations are in the same application, why make an HTTP request back to that same application?  Why not just invoke whatever logic you need to invoke from the controller method you're already in?

Comment: In postTestFile1(), unless there is an exception, you're not actually returning any result.  Is that what you're meaning to do?

Comment: No, although I'm not returning any result in postTestFile1(), the method do their work correctly. It reads and sends the file correctly, but in postTestFile2() I can't retrieve it. I don't know if I'm sending the file wrong, or I'm recovering it badly.